# How to make GridSplitter to "snap" into another element?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a data grid and a grid splitter:

[image]

The splitter is in the bottom and the data grid on the top and there is some empty space in between the two.

I think it would work fine if the grid splitter snapped into the data grid if its 24 or less units away from the data grid. Is this possible to archive?

Comment: Might be the row height is not fixed at 24 pixels. It could even vary from row to row - to be more precise, you should ask for the `GridSplitter` to snap to rows.

Comment: The row height is fixed at 24 units (1/96). That's not the problem, I just need this "per grid resize" or snapping.

Comment: Wondering if there is a SizeChanged event for a Grid cell - probably not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to snap per data grid rows with this:

```
private void GridSplitterDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // We want the grid splitter to snap in grid of 24 units.
    var excess = (int) FooDataGridRowDefinition.Height.Value % 24;

    if (excess == 0)
        return;

    FooDataGridRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(FooDataGridRowDefinition.Height.Value - excess);
}
```

The data grid rows are all 24 for me, I guess I could fetch them dynamically but that will do for now.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="FooDataGridRowDefinition" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" DragCompleted="GridSplitterDragCompleted" />

    <Foo Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```