# WPF Control, UserControl, Template confusion

Tags: wpf, xaml

Disclosure:

I am new to WPF, about a week into it.

Problem:

I am trying to modify the behavior of a GridSplitter, to make it snap to interesting positions, to show a label (that follows the splitter) with current position, to have a context menu driven from said label, etc.  I have prototyped all of this successfully on one gridsplitter in one simple test application, with a combination of XAML and some code behind.

Of note is that because the GridSplitter can't host content, I placed the label in the same grid cell as the splitter so that they move together.

So far so good....

Now I wish to replicate my work so that I can use my new GridSplitter functionality in place of the native control in many locations, and furthermore, I wish to have two variants, a horizontal and a vertical.  Sounds like inheritance...create a subclass derived from GridSplitter and add in the additional functionality.  But all of the reading I have done leaves me wondering how to go about this, and if this is even possible without starting over again and building my own GridSplitter from scratch?

Ideas welcome.  Until then I will resume the fetal position.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, post your current code and XAML, and if you can a screenshot of what you need

Comment: Let's just say I wish to add a text box that says "Hello, World!" that moves around with the GridSplitter, and encapsulate that functionality for re-use :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer might help you resolve your issue: [How to make GridSplitter to "snap" into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309955/how-to-make-gridsplitter-to-snap-into-another-element)

By subscribing to the `GridSplitterDragCompleted` event, you can insert your logic to snap to "interesting" positions.

Comment: My post states that I got this part working, thanks.  My problem revolves around making the new gridsplitter re-usable.

Comment: What you should do is create a new class that inherits from GridSplitter and use that control in it's place: `public class MyGridSplitter : GridSplitter { public MyGridSplitter(){ this.GridSplitterDragCompleted+= <handler>;}}`

Comment: A few more questions...
I did this, but when I use the derived class is hides properties of the base class such as "ResizeBehavior" and "Resize Direction".  Why is this?

Comment: One more:
How do I edit the derived control using XAML?  Do I have to do everything in code?

Comment: Ignore the above two questions....I think I get it.  Put code behind in derived class to modify behavior, use template in main app to achieve desired appearance.

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing, for better or for worse.  Created a usercontrol that encapsulated 4 native controls and associated functionality in code behind.  I then derived a new GridSplitter to add snap behavior, and programmatically add my new usercontrol to the parental grid as and when required.  It all seems to be working.

Thanks to all who helped here...it definitely spurred me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. create a new control derived from GridSplitter.
2. subscribe to DragCompleted event to implement snapping functionality like DLeh mentioned.
3. add a few new properties for Label , ContextMenu etc.
4. supply a style for your new control.

Answer (score 0):

This answers how to place content in the splitter

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Row 0" Background="Orange"/>
    <!--<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Background="Purple"/>-->
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <GridSplitter.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
                <TextBlock Text="TextBlock splitter" Background="Yellow" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </GridSplitter.Template>
    </GridSplitter>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Row 0" Background="Salmon"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This definitely answers one of my questions.  I am going to run with this and report back.  I'd vote up but I have no rep.

Comment: Technically it is supposed to be one question at a time.  In the WPF world you should rarely have to write you own control from scratch.